# express without a template

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a reason why I should avoid doing this?

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set("view options", {layout: false});
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

var html_dir = './views/';

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(html_dir  + "login.html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `res.write` and `res.end()` and just read the content's of the file vis the core `require('fs')` you can use `res.set(field, [value])` for the headers

[full docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html)

Comment: insted or `res.sendfile` you write `res.write(<html>)`